# How to rotate servo when there is object detected?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi4, robotics

currently I'm working with object detection yolov8 on raspberry pi. My project is to detect these three objects (aluminum can, plastic bottle, glass bottle). I already trained the dataset and export as best.pt file.

Now I got stuck on **how to rotate servo when there is object detected**. Here is my code.

```
from ultralytics import YOLO
import cv2
from ultralytics.yolo.utils.plotting import Annotator
import torch
from gpiozero import Servo
from time import sleep
from gpiozero.pins.pigpio import PiGPIOFactory

factory = PiGPIOFactory()

servo = Servo(12, min_pulse_width=0.5/1000, max_pulse_width=2.5/1000, pin_factory=factory)

model = YOLO('best.pt')
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
cap.set(3, 640)
cap.set(4, 480)

while True:
_, frame = cap.read()

img = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)

results = model.predict(img)

for r in results:
    
    annotator = Annotator(frame)
    
    boxes = r.boxes
    for box in boxes:
        
        b = box.xyxy[0]  # get box coordinates in (top, left, bottom, right) format
        c = box.cls
        annotator.box_label(b, model.names[int(c)])
       
      
frame = annotator.result()
  
cv2.imshow('YOLO V8 Obj Detection', frame)

#servo part

if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord(' '):
    break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: It looks like you've got most things ready to go (including setting up the servo on pin 12).  It's unclear how the detected class(es) map to servo motion: e.g. what does the servo do when there are no detections ? what about multiple detections ? and for a single detection, which servo value should be selected for which class (e.g. -1, 0, 1 for alluminium, plastic, glass) ? (e.g. `servo.value = box.cls - 1.0 # rempap 0,1,2 classes to -1, 0, 1 servo values`)